# compute_bill(['apple']) resulted in a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:
        total+= item
    return total
```

I know that there are solutions for this problem already , but i was not able to apply them in my program . I was learning python from codecademy and in this program , i am getting this error . I would appreciate if someone could thoroughly explain me the solution for same . 
thanx

Comment: If `food == ['apple']`, then `total+= item` becomes `0 += 'apple'`. What on earth did you *expect* that to do? Did you want `total += prices[item]`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanx , this helped me . but can you tell me what happens when we use total += prices[item]

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

The instructions in this particular exercise are not clear. You are basically **adding a string to an int** that's why you are getting this error. 
Run the code given below and it will solve your problem.

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0 
    for item in food: 
        total = total + prices[item]
    return total
```

Code snippet given above is basically going through prices dictionary which we created in the previous exercise. Each key corresponds to a price which is stored as int or float that is why you don't get an error when you use the above code.

Answer (score -1):

You are using a dictionary, looping through the dict will only produce keys.

When you loop through a dictionary as you do in `for item in food`, you are actually just looping through the dictionarys keys. So you need to use the keys to access the values in the `dict` you want to add to the total.

Edit: sorry didn't realise you specifically didn't want a solution so removed it.